# The Propositive mood in different speech levels

Tags: grammar, verb-endings, speech-levels

I want to use thee verb **살다** and express: "let us live together" [literally: with-me together let's-live]

1. Formal Levels:

**Hasoseo-che (하소서체)**

> 저랑 같이 사사사이다

**Hasipsio-che (하십시오체)**

> 저랑 같이 사십니다

> 저랑 같이 사시지요

**Hao-che (하오체)**

*Unavailable*

**Hage-che (하게체)**

> 나랑 같이 사세

**Haera-che(해라체)**

> 나랑 같이 살자

2. Informal Levels:

**Haeyo-che (해요체)**

*Unavailable*

**Hae-che (해체)**

> 나랑 같이 살자니까

*Please let me know if i have made any mistake ! Thank you !*

Comment: You should take into account 'ㄹ-drop', so they should be 사소서*, 삽시다/사십시다*, 사시지요*, 사시오*, 사세*, 살자, 살아요*, 살아* (* marks corrections).

Comment: I agree with krim

Comment: Thank @krim have edited it !

Comment: @krim I believe “사사이다” (“청유법,” indicating offers or suggestions) fits more than “사소서” (“명령법,” indicating orders and commands) here.

Comment: The “Let-us” form of “살다” in the “…하소서” register is “**사사이다**.” The conjugation “-(으)사이다” is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 살다 is a ㄹ-irregular verb, which means ㄹ drops and 살 becomes 사 before ㄴ,ㅂ, or ㅅ, like 사는 instead of 살으는 and 사세요 instead of 살으세요, etc (ㄹ stays on before the other consonants, as in 살면, 살아서, 살자).  So the conjugated forms you listed should be 사사이다, 사십니다, 사시지요, 사세, 살자, and 살자니까.
(note: 사르 is even worse than 살으 which might be used in certain contexts like songs and poems).

Also, 사사이다 is never used in modern Korean.  Nowadays 하소서체 survives only in religious prayers, but since you wouldn't say "Let's do something" to God, we can say 사사이다 is never used.

More important than the above is how you say it in 해요체 though.  You marked it as "unavailable", but shouldn't there be a propositive mood in such a commonly used speech form as 하소서체?

Well, there is no separate grammar form for it, but the common -아/어요 is also used for 청유 (proposition/suggestion, like "Let us ..."), in addition to the usual 설명 (explanation), 의문 (question), and 명령 (order).  Typically, it is preceded by 우리 or 같이 or both (e.g. 우리 (같이) 영화 보러 가요 = Let's go to the movies), but even without such a phrase it usually means a action proposition (e.g. 늦었으니까 택시 타요 = Let's take a cab since we're late).  This is because often only a proposition/suggestion makes sense when the implied subject is the speaker and the listener, since you wouldn't normally need to describe or question what the two of you're doing.

The same is also true for 해체 (우리 영화 보러 가), except that the usage is not as widespread in this case since it also has the commonly used -자 form.

Comment: Thank you Tony will just change it !

Comment: Can't you use 하소서체 with royalty ? You never know Joseon royal family might just come back .

Comment: I don't go to church, but I believe they still use the 하소서체 at church when praying to the Lord. No one else uses em

Comment: @Japanese Learner.  Royal family is not honored at all ever since Korea became a democratic republic in 1948. The last of them might have received some recognition in the 1930s to 1940s, but not after that, as far as I know.

Comment: Also, even in the extremely unlikely case Joseon's royal family makes a comeback, they will have to re-invent the royal verbal customs, because nobody alive remembers how to talk to royals "properly."  Even a king can't just order people to use certain grammar, if people have forgotten how to use it.

Comment: I honour the royal family, though @Tony . I think democracy is highly overated, just a way for rich people to  bend things to their with cunning. Plus democracy doesnt work in Asia look at China

Comment: @Japanese Learner.  I think it is not so much whether you have democracy or not, as you you see in Japan which is a democracy with well respected royalty.  In Korea, the Joseon dynasty went under completely, losing the country and taking down the royal family with it.  When they established the new country in 1948, they didn't want any holdover from the old regime which was responsible for the worst disaster in Korean history.  So neither the government nor the people have nostalgia for the old royal family.  They only exist in history.